# Übersetzung vom engl. Idiom "a token of my appreciation"

Tags: english-to-german, idiom

Neulich habe ich von folgendem englischen Idiom gehört:

> *a token of my appreciation*

Dieses wird verwendet, wenn man Dankbarkeit ausdrücken will. Als Beispiel betrachte man

> Please accept this present as a token of my appreciation.

Diesen Satz würde ich frei übersetzen als

> Bitte seien Sie/sei so nett, dieses Geschenk als Zeuge meiner Dankbarkeit anzunehmen.

Macht *als Zeuge meiner Dankbarkeit* auf Deutsch Sinn? Wenn nicht, gibt es ein Idiom, das dem englischen entspricht?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> als Zeuge meiner Dankbarkeit

ist in der Form unnatürlich übersetzt, und ein Konversationspartner wüsste nicht direkt, was gemeint ist. Vor allem sind "Zeugen" Personen, keine Gegenstände. Aber es gibt tatsächlich eine deutsche Entsprechung, nämlich "Zeichen meiner Wertschätzung". Als Satz:

> Bitte nehmen Sie dieses Geschenk als Zeichen meiner Wertschätzung an.

Randnotiz: "Bitte seien Sie so nett" ist eher eine formelle Art, eine Aufforderung zu äußern, als wirklich als Bitte gemeint. Das einfache "Bitte" ist hier also besser geeignet.

Comment: Vielen, vielen Dank!

Comment: Gern geschehen :)

Comment: Ganz simpel "*als Zeichen meiner Dankbarkeit*" geht natürlich auch.

Comment: "als Zeichen meiner Anerkennung" habe ich auch schon oft gehört

Answer (score 0):

Fast.

> Bitte seien Sie/sei so nett, dieses Geschenk als Zeugnis meiner Dankbarkeit anzunehmen.

Mit Zeugnis statt Zeuge geht es. Ein Zeuge ist eine Person.

Man kann natürlich Zeichen, Beleg, Ausdruck u. dgl. statt Zeugnis sagen - dies klingt gewisslich einen Deut moderner. Ob das erwünscht ist wäre eine andere Frage.

Comment: Im Kontext eines (wörtlichen) Gesprächs wäre "Zeugnis" allerdings unnatürlich, da es relativ hochgestochen klingt.

Comment: @yerforkferchips: Wörtlichem Gespräch im Ggs. zu gestischem? Gilt das für "a token of my appreciation" nicht auch, dass es hochgestochen klingt? Unnatürlich ist Sprache immer.

Comment: Im wörtlichen Gespräch insbesondere. "a token of my appreciation" bzw. die von mir erwähnte Entsprechung sind zumindest Idiome, und denen verzeiht man üblicherweise ihre (eventuelle) Hochgestochenheit. Wenn man sie dann noch hochgestochener umfomuliert, fällt es erst recht auf.

Comment: Man kann natürlich Zeichen, Beleg u. dgl. sagen. Auch nach Hinweis an der umständlichen Formel "wörtlichem Gespräch" festzuhalten, wo Gespräch schon alles sagen würde, weist Dich als Fachmann für Hochgestochenes jedenfalls aus. "Zeugnis" ist natürlich eine idiomatische Wendung, daher greift Deine Parade ins Leere.

Comment: Ich habe nur eine Betonung auf "wörtlich" gelegt, weil die Grenze zwischen "wörtlich" und "schriftlich" verschwimmt, z.B. durch Messenger-Dienste. Mir ist nicht klar, wie ein einzelnes Wort, das ein anderes im Kontext einer existierenden Redewendung ersetzt, ein Idiom sein soll.

Comment: @yerforkferchips: Der Gegensatz zu *schriftlich* ist aber *mündlich*, nicht *wörtlich*. Wörter sind auch die Elemente des schriftlichen Ausdrucks. Dass Zeugnis als einzelnes Wort kaum idiomatisch sein kann muss ich aber kleinlaut einräumen.

Comment: Das stimmt, die Korrektur kann ich annehmen.